# HtmlUnit: Request website from server in a specific language

Tags: java, cookies, web, htmlunit, http-accept-language

**I am looking for a clean/simple way in HtmlUnit to request a webpage from a server in a specific language.**

To do this i have been trying to request "bankofamerica.com" for their homepage in spanish instead of english.

This is what i have done so far:

I tried to set "Accept-Language" header to "es" in the Http request. I did this using:

```
myWebClient.addRequestHeader("Accept-Language" , "es");
```

It did not work. I then created a web request with the following code:

```
URL myUrl = new URL("https://www.bankofamerica.com/");
WebRequest myRequest = new WebRequest(myUrl);
myRequest.setAdditionalHeader("Accept-Language", "es");
HtmlPage aPage = myWebClient.getPage(myRequest);
```

Since this failed too i printed out the request object for this url , to check if these headers are being set.

```
[<url="https://www.bankofamerica.com/", GET, EncodingType[name=application/x-www-form-urlencoded], [], {Accept-Language=es, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, Accept=*/*}, null>]
```

So the server is being requested for a spanish page but in response its sending the homepage in english (the response header has the value of Content-Language set to en-US)

I did find a hack to retrieve the BOA page in spanish. I visited this page and used the chrome developer tool to get the cookie value from the request 
header. I used this value to do the following:

```
 myRequest.setAdditionalHeader("Cookie", "TLTSID= ........._LOCALE_COOKIE=es-US; CONTEXT=es_US; INTL_LANG=es_US; LANG_COOKIE=es_US; hp_pf_anon=anon=((ct=+||st=+||fn=+||zc=+||lang=es_US));..........1870903; throttle_value=43");
```

I am guessing the answer lies somewhere here.

**Here lies my next question. If i am writing a script to retrieve 100 different websites in Spanish (ie Assuming they all have their pages in the spanish) . Is there a clean way in HtmlUnit to accomplish this.**

(If cookies is indeed a solution then to create them in htmlunit you need to specify the domain name. One would have to then create cookies for each of the 100 sites. As far as i know there is no way in HtmlUnit to do something like:

Cookie langCookie = new Cookie("All Domains","LANG_COOKIE","es_US");
myWebClient.getCookieManager().addCookie(langCookie);)

**NOTE:** I am using HtmlUnit 2.12 and setting BrowserVersion.CHROME in the webclient

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first concern the clear/simple(/only?) way of requesting a webpage in a particular language is, as you said, to set the HTTP `Accept-Language` request header to the locale(s) you want. That is it.

Now the fact that you request a page in a particular language doesn't mean that you will actually get a page in that language. The server has to be set up to process that HTTP header and respond accordingly. Even if a site has a whole section in spanish it doesn't mean that the site is responding to the HTTP header.

A clear example of this is the page you provided. I performed a quick test on it and found that it is clearly not responding accordingly to the `Accept-Language` I've set (which was `es`). Hitting the home page using `es` resulted in getting results in english. However, the page has a link that states `En Español` which means `In Spanish` the page does switch to spanish and you get redirected to `https://www.bankofamerica.com?request_locale=es_US`.

So you might be tempted to think that the page handles the locale by a request parameter. However, that is not (only) the case. Because if you then open the home page again (without the locale parameter) you will see the Spanish version again. That is clearly a proof that they are being stored somewhere else, most likely in the session, which will most likely be handled by cookies.

That can easily be confirmed by opening a private session or clearing the cookies and confirming this behaviour (I've just done that).

I think that explains the mystery of the webpage existing in Spanish but being fetched in English. (Note how most bank webpages do not conform to basic standards such as responding to simple HTTP requests... and they are handling our money!)

Regarding your second question, it would be like asking *What is the recipe to not get ill ever?*. It just doesn't depend on you. Also note that your first concerned used the word *request* while your second concern used the word *retrieve*. I think it should be clear by now that you can only be 100% sure of what you request but not of what you retrieve.

Regarding setting a value in a cookie manually, that is technically possible. However, that is just like adding another parameter in a get request: `http://domain.com?login=yes`. The parameter will only be processed by the server if it is expecting it. Otherwise, it will be ignored. That is what will happen to the value in your cookie.

Summary: There are standards to follow. You can try to use them but if the one in the other side doesn't then you won't get the results you expect. Your best choice: do your best and follow the standards.